# awk for sort lines in file

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, awk

I have a file which needs to sort on basis of column and the column is fixed length based column i.e. from character 5 to 10.

example file:

```
0120456789bcdc hsdsjjlofk
01204567-9 __abc __hsdsjjjiejks
01224-6777 abcddd hsdsjjjpsdpf
012645670- abccccd hsdsjjjopp
```

I tried `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="4 10" '{print|"$2 sort -n"}' file` but it does not give proper output.

Comment: Learn how to format your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So what is the expected output? Read also [ask].

Comment: hek2mgl and fedorqui thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` for this

```
$ sort -k1.5,1.10 file
01224-6777 abcddd hsdsjjjpsdpf
01204567-9 __abc __hsdsjjjiejks
012645670- abccccd hsdsjjjopp
0120456789bcdc hsdsjjlofk
```